# Android - How to stop the service's previous execution before restarting it?

Tags: android, service, timer, preferenceactivity

I am trying to start a Service from my PreferenceActivity. I want to start a service on every onPreferenceChangeListenr.

I have four conditions in my onPreferenceChangeListener and each condition has to start same Service with different values.

When i change the preference for the first time it starts the service and when i change the preference second time it starts the service with new value but it does not stop the execution of the previous condition so now i have a service which is producing results for two conditions and if i change the preference third time, it starts producing result for three condition but what i need is to run this service only for the current condition.

Here is my `PreferenceActivity's` code:-

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity
{
private Button button;
ListPreference lp;
private Context context;
private long duration;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    context = this;
    lp = (ListPreference)findPreference("autoduration");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, BackService.class);
    lp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener()
    {
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue)
        {
            String newSelection = newValue.toString();
            int index = lp.findIndexOfValue(newSelection);
            stopService(intent);
            if(index==0)
            {
                duration = 15000;
            }
            else if(index==1)
            {
               duration = 12000;
            }
            else if(index==2)
            {
                duration = 10000;
            }
            else if(index==3)
            {
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
                filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
                BroadcastReceiver receiver = new ScreenReceiver();
                registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
            }
            intent.putExtra("duration", duration);
            startService(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });


}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
}
```

And its my service code which should be affected by my PreferenceActivity. :-

```
private static Timer myTimer = new Timer();
public static final String TAG = "BackService";
private MainTask mainTask = new MainTask();    

 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        Long duration = intent.getLongExtra("duration", 7000);
        startServices(duration);
    }

public void startServices(Long dur)
    {
        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mainTask,0,dur);
    }
private class MainTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e(TAG, "I am HERE");
        }
    }
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver :-

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static boolean screenOn = true;
private static final String TAG = "ScreenReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "I am receiver");
    }
}
}
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong so Please Help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service may be getting restarted without you realizing. However, you have a problem because in that case, the `myTimer` is not getting torn down. You need to implement the `onDestroy` method in your class, determine if your service is getting stopped (because somewhere `stopSelf` or `Context.stopService` is being called).

If so, you should remove the `static` modifier from the `myTimer` variable, so that it doesn't hang around between starts of the service and in the `onDestroy` method you need to call `myTimer.cancel()` to stop it, since otherwise it will just hang around and you won't have any reference to it to cancel it.

In your `startServices` method, add the following before the call to `myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate`:

```
mainTask.cancel();
mainTask = new MainTask();
```

Comment: it is still behaving the same. :(

Comment: Then the other possibility is that this is a result of the Timer object being static. I'll edit my answer to explain why that could be a problem.

Comment: yeah its working now. :) you were right i wasn't canceling the mytimer object. Now i am calling myTimer.cancel() in onDestroy() and it's working as it shoud. Many thanks. :)

Comment: sorry to disturb you again but i am facing a very small problem right now and don't want to start a new thread for this small problem. I have edited my code. Could you please take a look? and tell me why i am unable to register my `BroadcastReceiver` in case of `(index==3)`.